# Enabling DB2 Database for Full Text Searching

Tags: db2, sles, full-text-search

I'm trying to enable full text searching on a DB2 V9.5 database, SuSe Enterprise Linux.

Net Search Extender has been installed and db2text service starts without problems.

When I execute the following command:

```
db2text ENABLE DATABASE FOR TEXT CONNECT TO <database_name>;
```

I get the error message:

```
CTE0190 Executable program "cteadmsv" could not be started.
```

Has anybody run into this before?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting IBM support, this is the solution they provided:

1. stop db2 netsearch extender (db2text stop)
2. stop db2. (db2stop)
3. as db2 instance owner remove the .fenced file (in sqllib/adm)
4. touch .fenced.
5. It should now have the correct ownership
6. restart db2 (db2start)
7. restart netsearch extender (db2text start)

That worked for us.